# I can't set up a server on windows 7 to listen on to a specific port

Tags: c, winapi, networking, network-programming

I want to learn some network programming in C with winapi.

That's the code. The problem. It runs only on port 5555, not the one I specified. It compiles and runs. The windows firewall pops up and I authorize the application. I scanned my computer with nmap using connect() parameter and it closes the connection making me sure this application is running on port 5555. Yet, it doesn't display anything on the screen, except for when the connection is terminated.

The commented part is the other way I tried to setup the server. I tried two approaches and both didn't work perfectly. Thanks in advance.

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

struct sockaddr_in my_addr, *p;

//ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(192.168.0.102)
my_addr.sin_port = htons(9998);
memset(my_addr.sin_zero,'\0', sizeof(my_addr.sin_zero));
/*
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
*/  

// Resolve the server address and port

/*iResult = getaddrinfo("192.168.0.102", "3222", &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}*/

//Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(p->sin_family, p->sin_socktype, p->sin_protocol);

//ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind( ListenSocket, 192.168.0.102, (int)p->sin_addrlen);

if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {

    printf("Running on port: %d\n", p->sin_port)

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    // Echo the buffer back to the sender
        iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
        if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else  {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*It compiles ...*" are you sure?

Comment: Absolutely, but I had to set manually -l Ws2_32 in linker settings inside Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of errors in your code.

Try this:

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    short my_port = 9998;

    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.102");
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(my_port);

    // Resolve the server address and port

    //Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Listening on port: %hd\n", my_port);

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    printf("Client connected\n");

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Or this:

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    short my_port = 9998;
    char my_port_str[6];
    sprintf(my_port_str, "%hu", my_port);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port

    iResult = getaddrinfo("192.168.0.102", my_port_str, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Listening on port: %hd\n", my_port);

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    printf("Client connected\n");

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do
    {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
        {
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```